# Clearing Outlook Message dirty flag

Tags: c#, outlook, message

How can I clear the dirty flag of an open outlook message so the message Save? Dialog is not presented to the user?

Comment: Assuming this is about programming, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can call MailItem.Close(olDiscard)